# CanCanCan Role must exist + User already exists error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

I've used to devise to handle user signup/signin. I'm now trying to use CanCan to implement admin, moderator and a normal user.
I want the default signup to be of 'registered' or normal user. I followed their guide and did this.
In seeds.rb:

```
['admin', 'moderator', 'registered'].each do |role|
    Role.find_or_create_by({name: role})
end
```

In role.rb:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end
```

In user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :todos
  belongs_to :role
  before_create :set_default_role

  private
  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= Role.find_by_name('registered')
  end
end
```

However, whenever I click on sign up. I get an error on the page saying 'Role must exist' and this is what I get in console:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-25 10:38:27 +0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yBNCK6YInQTx3YsYFSDTToPMpS4NCUz0bTLxGxyeFq2zHWTJWwkkHqcblbsN+7CJEQEsfjtC2VlbuPvVyomv5Q==", "user"=>{"email"=>"umar@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "umar@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 149ms (Views: 13.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Plus I haven't touched ability.rb yet. What seems to be wrong?

Comment: I've checked the contents of my User table in the database through console and there's no sign of **umar@gmail.com**. So the question is why would it rollback transaction?

Comment: can you try `User.create!(email:...password:...)`. notice the bang`!` at the end of create method, try running with it.

Comment: @Abhinay what create method are you talking about? Do you want me to do this in the console?
I've tried to manually create a User through console and it works smoothly :)

Comment: Yes I was talking about running it in console. are you saying it is able to create user with email `umar@gmail.com`?

Comment: @Abhinay sorry I tried that yesterday with admin. I've tried doing it again:
`irb(main):001:0> User.create!(email: 'umar@gmail.com', password: '123456')
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "umar@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Role must exist)
`

Comment: I've also added a strong parameter in application_controller.

Comment: `separate lines inside comments?` did not get you there but if you are talking about catching this exception and displaying it in some other way then you can always catch it inside your application controller `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid ...` but this would be overkill at this stage.

Comment: **umar@gmail.com** does not exist in the database and I am unable to signup with this email or any other email. It always says 'Role must exist'. My private 'set_default_role' method is not working somehow!

Comment: You might want to add role callback with `before_validation :set_default_role, on: [:create, :update]`  instead of `before_create`

Comment: @Abhinay that worked! Could you please tell me what's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of setting role at the `creation` phase, you should be setting it before validation like below:

```
before_validation :set_default_role, on: [:create, :update]
```

If you look at the doc which shows the list of all callbacks in the same order in which they will get called, you will notice that `validation` callback is called before `create` callback.

Now, Activerecord finds that user doesn't have `role` attached to it at the `validation` phase, it throws the same error which you are seeing.

for more details on callbacks please refer this doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense!